# Setting up a SQL server outside the domain

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

im very new to this. I've set up an account "SQLBOX" thats on the a network, but not connected to the domain. I have installed an instance of SQL Server 2008 and am trying to connect to it from another machine on the network but am getting "Cannot connect to "SQLBOX"". From the "SQLBOX" i can connect to sqlservers on the domain, but not vice-versa. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if the description isn't great.

EDIT

I can ping the box from a machine on the domain

Comment: Are you trying to connect to sqlbox using sql server enterprise manager or using a database link between the non-domain and the domain?

Comment: Im connecting using SQL Server Management Studio on a machine on the domain, to the server (not on the domain) "SQLBOX"

Comment: Not great. What have you tried? Did you enable TCP/IP on the SQL Server? Did you allow remote connections? Is your firewall open on the right port? Lots of things we need to know before we can help.

Comment: I've enabled TCP/IP on the SQL Server. How do you allow remote connections (i assume your not talking about remote desktop connections)? It's a fresh box and has no firewall on it yet.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The default for SQL Server 2008 is:

1. sa account is disabled by default
2. port 1433 is not actually listening, you need to enable it and make sure you bind it to the ip address that your expecting (not a required step).  (i usually disable IPv6 on my network adapter on this one to simplify a little)
3. if your using the SA account, enable SQL authentication because its not enabled by default
4. verify that windows firewall added an exception for SQL Server process
5. finally, network auth sometimes will get you and so if your having trouble, change the user account that the SQL server process runs under.  (i usually run my SQL server as the currently logged in user to get around that problem)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have SQL Authentication enabled on the server outside the domain (so you're not using Built-In Windows authentication).

You'll have to then create SQL Accounts for every user you want to connect to your server.

Comment: I've done that. I still get "Cannot connect to SQLBOX" from the machine on the domain. Is there anything else i need to change on the server? Cheers

Comment: Have you tried accessing the box using the IP address rather than the machine name? You could be having problems with a WINS lookup failing fromt he domain to the machine outside the domain.

Comment: Yeah, i've tried using the IP address, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Check the firewall rules on both machines and between them. Port 1433 needs to be open.

Answer (score 1):

Run SQL Configuration and make sure the TCP/IP port and IP enabled. It's disabled by default

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to connect to your new SQLBOX with the SSMS, aren't you? For this it is not necessary that the server is part of your domain as long as your are using the SQL authentication and not the Windows authentication of SQL Server.

On the new box you should check which IP address the new box has and use this IP instead of the name to connect to the server using the SSMS.

If this does not succeed then it would be useful if you could provide us with exact error message which you receive when trying to connect.